# I need help may someone please explain why my setinterval is acting goofy?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Well I tried to set intervals for the code, but it moves only onceL

```
function moveAllTriangles(){
    var spike = document.getElementById("spike");
    var mg = setInterval(function(){moveTriangle();},1125);
    function moveTriangle(){
        var moved = 100;
        spike.style.left = (750 - moved) + 'px';
        moved++;  
    }
}
```

please explain why this is broken thank you.

Comment: Define 'broken'; what is happening at the moment, and what *should* be happening that is not currently happening?

Comment: Because you reset the variable back to 100 every time.

Comment: Hi! Please read the [Tour] and [ask].

Comment: Also, instead of `function(){moveTriangle();}` just use `moveTriangle`.

Comment: You're redefining moved every time it runs, so your moved++ is doing nothing

Comment: Why "off-topic" ?? In my point of view the problem is clear enough. Have a little mercy for the newcomers !

Comment: Yeah I believe it's a fair enough question, and isn't really a typo, more a functional mistake.

Comment: I don't think it's unfair at all, in fact I think http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ explains the closure and score quite well, especially *"Examine variables and their contents at runtime."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this more clear since you seem to be having some trouble: you *redefined* `moved` inside your interval, so every time it runs, it gets set back to 100.

You need to initialize that *outside* the interval.

```
function moveAllTriangles(){
    var spike = document.getElementById("spike");
    var moved = 100;

    function moveTriangle(){
        spike.style.left = (750 - moved) + 'px';
        moved++;  
    }

    var mg = setInterval(moveTriangle, 1125);
}
```

Also, [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) takes a function name or a closure, you don't *need* to use a closure, just pass the name of the function you've already defined.